# latex symbol for covering relation in posets

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols

Is there a package with LaTeX symbols for the poset relations "covers" and "is covered by", as seen in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation? I've tried creating ⋅> and <⋅ symbols on my own using \cdot, <, and >, but the spacing between the two symbols tends to vary, as does the surrounding space, in ways that don't look good.

Comment: The [`amssymb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) package provides `\lessdot` and `\gtrdot`.

Comment: Look at the first result offered by [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html): http://i.imgur.com/qoLQFkL.png

Comment: @Gonzalo: Wow; detexify is cool!  Thanks for letting me know about it.